# is that Ok to call multiple actions at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have multiple reducers and I need to send separate actions for each of them on a click so this is what I did:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={[styles.button, styles.edit]}
    onPress={()=>{
       this.props.toggleCurrentTask(this.props.task);
       this.props.triggerUpdating(id);
    }}
>
   <Text>Edit</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

but the `toggleCurrentTask` action didn't work and I was struggling for a while, at the end just replacing them solved my problem!
like this:

```
onPress={()=>{
   this.props.triggerUpdating(id);
   this.props.toggleCurrentTask(this.props.task);
}}
```

So I thought maybe calling two actions at the same time is a bad practice. If that's the case, what should I do instead?

Comment: Multiple api calls are not bad practice, depends on your program. You can do 1 API call and process your data in backend or you can do n-API calls in frontend and process this data with different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, but you can also have different reducers react to the same action (type): In your example the reducer storing the `updating` state could change its state when a `toggleCurrentTask` action is dispatched:

```
const TOGGLE_CURRENT_TASK = 'task/TOGGLE_CURRENT_TASK';

/* update reducer */

const updatingState = {
    isUpdating: false
}

const updatingReducer = (state = updatingState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_CURRENT_TASK:
            return {
                ...state,
                isUpdating: true
            }
    }
}

/* task reducer */
const taskState = {}

const taskReducer = (state = taskState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_CURRENT_TASK:
            return {
                ...state,
                activeTasks: action.task
            }
    }
}
```

IMO this keeps your React component cleaner and scales better, imagine your have to dispatch five different actions in the event handler instead of just two.